# Getting error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when using this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using following script in my page and because of this script only i am getting this error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

**Sript**

```
if($('section.landing_page').parent('.home1').is(':visible')){
    $('body>div,body>header,body>section,body>footer').not($('.home1,.video_popup,#download_app_popup,#display')).addClass('hidden_body');
} else {
    $('.hidden_body').removeClass('hidden_body');
};
```

With this script i am checking if this particular section is visible then whole website will set to display none except some popup's else website will show.

This is because i have cookie set for that section if user is coming second time then that section is not visible but this script is showing stack size exceed error.

I know there are so many question about it but i am not getting any answer specific to my script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We may need to see more code. Code within which this script is included and the caller?

Comment: This is independent script and if i remove this script page is working fine

Comment: I dont think the script you have posted is causing the error coz `Uncaught RangeError` is generated when there is some script which is executing indefinitely/ until it hits call stack limit (something like infinite loop)

Comment: @RRR exactly..thats why i wonder why page is working fine after removing this script...

Comment: @RRR try opening this link http://website_wordpress-dev.crownit.in/ this is the website in which landing section comes only once so if you will load it second time error will not come as cookie is set for that section it will come only first time so please check the error at first time..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
  if($('section.landing_page').parent('.home1').is(':visible')){
    $('body div,body header,body section,body footer').not($('.home1,.video_popup,#download_app_popup,#display')).addClass('hidden_body');
} else {
    $('.hidden_body').removeClass('hidden_body');
};
```

Comment: you have just removed `>` which will catch multilevel div's it will create more events..